# Why my license for gurobi do not work every time I reboot my laptop?

Tags: matlab, gurobi

I use gurobi for matlab with academic license on my laptop, which runs ubuntu 20.04. It works well after I install it and setup my license according to the guide, while every time I reboot my machine, I can not use gurobi any longer as it says `Gurobi error 10009: HostID mismatch (licensed to d5daa0d8, hostid is d0cff4dc)`. But actually, my laptop's hostid does not match neither of the above(according to the command `hostid`). Are there anyone can tell me what's going on and how to solve it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: These are both commercially licensed products, ask the support team for the software vendors if you're having an issue with the license they've provided...

Comment: The hostid your license is bound to, is not the result of running `hostid` on your machine. You need to run `grbgetkey`, a Gurobi tool, to see the hostid of your machine.